# Strange 100% CPU usage in iOS 9 with UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview, ios9

I have a tableView, in each cell there is a collectionView. Sometimes when I know there is new data in collectionViews, I call `reloadData()` on collectionView. Most of the time this routine works, but but sometimes is starts to use 100% of CPU, memory usage increasing, GUI is blocked, and at a point app will crash. If I do not let reload collectionView, then all works well, only the content invalid in the collectionView. What is going on, in iOS 8 it was not a problem to call `reloadData()` from `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("movie") as! MovieTableViewCell

    //..

    if cell.rcvc == nil {

        let cvfl = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        cvfl.scrollDirection = .Horizontal
        cell.rcvc = RatingCollectionViewController(collectionViewLayout: cvfl)

        self.addChildViewController(cell.rcvc!)
        let v = cell.viewWithTag(5)!
        v.addSubview(cell.rcvc!.view)
        cell.rcvc!.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
        cell.rcvc!.view.frame = v.bounds
    }

    cell.rcvc!.movie = movie

    if enableReloadRatingCollectionViews {

        cell.rcvc!.collectionView!.reloadData() // <--- if I comment, not crashes
    }

    return cell
}
```

### UPDATE

I have updated my code like @dasblinkenlight suggest, I am not calling `reloadData` anymore from `cellforRowAtIndexPath`, but now call `reloadData` for all `collectionView`s form outside when certain user interaction triggers it. But it still crashes sometimes, any idea why?

```
itemTableViewController!.tableView.reloadData()
for sv in collectionViews.allObjects {

    (sv as! UICollectionView).reloadData()
}
```

[image]

Comment: I completely misunderstood your issue, I did not see that the reload was for `UICollectionView` *inside* `UITableViewCell`. I'm sure there's some timing issue going on here, but my prior recommendation is irrelevant.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your crash is caused by an infinite recursion which overflows the stack. Can you post the stack trace from the crash?

Comment: @TamásZahola That's what I thought too, before I realized that the call to `reloadData` is done on a completely different view controller. OP has a collection view inside each cell.

Comment: I am not sure if you've seen [this article](https://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell/) but you may want to take a look, because it explains things that may be related to what you are doing.

Comment: Hmmm, it seems there's no 2nd party code in the stack trace and it's not even a stack overflow.

Comment: Could you log the `collectionView`s' frames when you call `reloadData` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of reloading the nested `collectionView`, I implemented a `configureCell` method, that reset cell, and for all the visible cell I call `configureCell`. That is my fix, and so the infinite loop can avoid.